# Showing selected values in summary from multiselectlistpreference

Tags: android

I Have a MultiSelectListPreference which shows a the list of weeks when user close the multi select dialog i would like to show the selected values in summary using `%s` but it only works with ListPreference. Is there any solution for this?

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
        android:id="@+id/pref_select_week"
        android:defaultValue="@array/week_array_values"
        android:entries="@array/week_array"
        android:entryValues="@array/week_array_values"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pref_time"
        android:key="keyZodiacSign"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:title="Select Days" />
```

Answer (score 4):

First add an extension method to `MultiSelectListPreference` which sets the summary from the selected values:

```
fun MultiSelectListPreference.setSummaryFromValues(values: Set<String>) {
    summary = values.map {entries[findIndexOfValue(it)]}.joinToString(", ")
}
```

And then in eg. `onCreateView` of your `PreferenceFragmentCompat`:

```
val columnSelect = findPreference("EXPORT_COLUMNS") as MultiSelectListPreference
columnSelect.onPreferenceChangeListener = Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
    columnSelect.setSummaryFromValues(newValue as Set<String>)
    true
}
columnSelect.setSummaryFromValues(columnSelect.values)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create custom version of MultiSelectListPreference and ovveride `getSummary` method like this:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getSummary() {
    CharSequence cs = super.getSummary();
    String summary = cs.toString();

    if (summary.contains("%s")) {
        String text = "";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        CharSequence[] entries = getEntries();
        if(entries.length > 0) {
            CharSequence[] entryValues = getEntryValues();
            Set<String> values = getValues();
            int pos = 0;

            for (String value : values) {
                pos++;
                int index = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < entryValues.length; i++) {
                    if (entryValues[i].equals(value)) {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                builder.append(entries[index]);
                if (pos < values.size())
                    builder.append(", ");
            }
            text = builder.toString();
        }
        summary = String.format(summary, text);
    }

    return summary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin at least, you could add a function to the MultiSelectListPreference class as follows:

```
import android.support.v14.preference.MultiSelectListPreference

fun MultiSelectListPreference.useSelectionAsSummary() {
    var summary = ""
    for (value in this.values) {
        if (summary.isNotEmpty()) {
            summary += ", "
        }
        val i = this.findIndexOfValue(value.toString())
        summary += this.entries[i]
    }
    this.summary = summary
}
```

Usage as follows:

```
prefSelectWeek.useSelectionAsSummary()
```